# "light box" styled window to display texts like "Terms of Use" and "Privacy Policy"

Tags: jquery, html

On my web app, I'm looking for a mechanism that'll allow me to pop a static window on top of my page where texts will be displayed with a scroll bar. I'd like the frame of that window to have a "X close" button. Simple.

I know there are some JQuery "lightbox" implementations for photos. Is there something similar where I can just show/scroll text?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use jQuery UI Dialog. You can "pop" a modal dialog with that widget.

Here is an example snippet from http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/:

```
<script>
$(function() {


    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
        height: 140,
        modal: true
    });
});
</script>



<div class="demo">

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
<p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it dims out the page content.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite for Modal windows is the standard jQuery UI Dialog box.  It's simple, lightweight, and already available via jQuery UI, which I already run.

Simply build a div and call a `$('#id').dialog()`

Answer (score 0):

highslide will do exactly what you are looking for you can see how i used it here: http://gitastudents.com/~clarkb/group1/Courses.html

highslide is here: http://highslide.com/editor/
you can configure it exactly how you want it to look
it is easy to implement just follow the instructions given